# Use custom color from assets in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

I am making an app in SwiftUI and want to change the color of the navigation bar title text to a custom color I made in the assets folder.

I want to set the foreground color to my custom "jpurple" color. When I try to implement it, it doesn't work:

```
init() {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: Color("jpurple")]
}
```

Comment: I moved the title to the question and shortened the title significantly. This makes the question appear more general on the homepage and makes it clear at a glance what you are trying to do. Now it's on you though! You should explain what "doesn't work" mean. Right now it could be anything like a compiler error, a runtime error or just behaviour you didn't expect. Make it clear what the issue is (by including error messages copy-pasted into your question for example). Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter into the initialiser function of the app, and modify the navigation bar's appearance. The code to do so is below.

```
 init() {
      UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "jpurple")]
    }
```